# What do you call it when the arrival platform of a train changes?

Tags: expressions

I am not used to English conversation, so I have a question about the language normally used for a specific situation.

For example, a train is supposed to arrive at platform #3; however, it arrives at platform #9 instead. What would this situation be called?

Does calling this a *platform alteration* sound ok?

Comment: Then, how about this? both are okay? https://m.youtube.com/watch?v=W5Xe22VoeZE

Comment: Everyone knows it arrives at Platform 9 3/4.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In British railway announcements in English, this is always called a **platform alteration,** as your [video](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=W5Xe22VoeZE) — apparently shot at Lincoln — demonstrates.

That shows the standard recording, with the different parts of the announcement spliced toegther electronically. The phrase "This is a platform alteration" is always used in these situations.

Chris H has [commented](/q/507179#comment1227884_507189) that in Welsh the phrase used translates to *newydd platfform* (literally “new platform”) and it’s possible that the idiomatic phrases in Gaelic differ too.

Comment: +1 but a minor quibble: *British* doesn't always mean English and *The phrase "This is a platform alteration" is always used* don't quite work. I'm quite used to hearing *newydd platfform* (those announcements are about the limit of my understanding of Welsh).

Comment: @ChrisH Hope the answer is better now.

Comment: More than I expected!

Comment: Thanks everyone. then, I wonder if it is possible to use "Platform alteration" or "newydd platform" outside UK. maybe the former one is easier to understand for the people from other countries, I think.

Comment: @LucianoJeong "Newydd platfform" (two ds, pronounced /θ/; two fs) isn't English. It's Welsh. It's just that it translates to "new platform" in English -- and while that phrase isn't what is generally used, "the 1441 to Peterborough has a new platform and will now depart from Platform 5" would be understood.

Answer (score 2):

In North America, it's called a **platform change** or just a **change of platform**.

At least from [Google Books Ngram Viewer](https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=platform%20change%2Cchange%20of%20platform%2Cplatform%20alteration&year_start=1800&year_end=2000&corpus=17&smoothing=3&share=&direct_url=t1%3B%2Cplatform%20change%3B%2Cc0%3B.t1%3B%2Cchange%20of%20platform%3B%2Cc0#t1%3B%2Cplatform%20change%3B%2Cc0%3B.t1%3B%2Cchange%20of%20platform%3B%2Cc0), *platform change* is the more common in printed form. (And *platform alteration* doesn't exist at all.)

[image: platform change]

I will also say that I have never heard *platform alteration* before—either where I am in Canada or at any time that I've travelled to the States. (I have also been to the UK, but have never actually heard any announcement of a change—or alteration—at all, so I can't personally speak to the wording used.)